# Making an S shape with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to reproduce this layout structure using flex.

```
ooo
  o
ooo
o
ooo
  o
ooo
```

I can achieve this with regular display block/inline-block but I'm wrapping some elements just for positioning, and it feels hackish.

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-size:11px;
}

.new {
  display:block;
}

.right {
  margin-left:200px;
}

* {
  font-size:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.alignright {
    direction: rtl;
}

section {
   width:300px;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <span class="row">1</span>
  <span class="row">2</span>
  <span class="row">3</span>

  <span class="new right">4</span>
  <span class="new right">5</span>

  <div class="alignright">
  <span class="row t">6</span>
  <span class="row t">7</span>
  <span class="row t">8</span>
  </div>
  
  <span class="new">9</span>
  <span class="new">10</span>

  <span class="row">11</span>
  <span class="row">12</span>
  <span class="row">13</span>
  
</section>
```

Is this possible to do in flex, without the `DIV` wrappings and multiple classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This can be achieved using flexbox and `nth-child`

You can use `nth-child` to mark which elements are to align to the left and right and flexboxes `order` property means you do not need any nesting.

The following changes are required:

- Add `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `section` to make it's children use the flexbox model and wrap onto new lines
- Add `span:nth-child(-n+5)` with `order: 1;` - this will tell the first 5 elements to be ordered first
- Add `span:nth-child(4), span:nth-child(5)` with `margin-right: 200px;` - this will force the fourth and fifth elements to take up the extra space on the right and push subsequent elements onto a new line
- Add `span:nth-child(8)` with `order: 2;` - this will order the eighth element after the first five
- Add `span:nth-child(7)` with `order: 3;` - this will order the seventh element after the eighth
- Add `span:nth-child(6)` with `order: 4;` - this will order the sixth element after the seventh
- Add `span:nth-child(n+9)` with `order: 5;` - this will order the last 5 elements after the sixth
- Add `span:nth-child(9), span:nth-child(10)` with `margin-left: 200px;` - this will force the ninth and tenth elements to take up the extra space on the left and push subsequent elements onto a new line

```css
* {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}
span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
span:nth-child(-n+5) {
  order: 1;
}
span:nth-child(4),
span:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
  order: 4;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
  order: 3;
}
span:nth-child(8) {
  order: 2;
}
span:nth-child(n+9) {
  order: 5;
}
span:nth-child(9),
span:nth-child(10) {
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
  <span>11</span>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>13</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible ot have blocks 6,7,8 in reverse order? Like in my example, i'm using the .alignright class to give direction from right to left. I assume I'll need to wrap these blocks to achieve this?

Comment: Apologies @ditto, didn't see that requirement, give me a sec I'll edit my example.

Comment: @ditto, please see my updated answer. The CSS is a bit more complex but there is no need for any classes or nesting.

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect.

Comment: No problem @ditto.